# Melt only highest values in matrix

Tags: r, matrix, optimization

I have a large, square matrix containing correlations between each row or column:

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(5000 * 5000), nrow = 5000, dimnames = list(
    paste0("ID", seq_len(5000)), paste0("ID", seq_len(5000))))
```

I want to extract the top 100,000 unique pairs from this matrix (i.e., ID1—ID2 is the same as ID2—ID1), then convert them to a data frame. Currently, I am using this code:

```
corDat <- reshape2::melt(mat, varnames = c("id.A", "id.B"),
                       value.name = "value", na.rm = T)
corDat <- corDat[as.character(corDat$id.A) < as.character(corDat$id.B),]
corDat <- corDat[order(-corDat$value),]
top_n <- 100000
corDat <- corDat[seq_len(top_n),]
```

The result:

```
head(corDat)

           id.A   id.B    value
19316931 ID1931 ID3864 5.658092
14312231 ID2231 ID2863 5.416562
3225529   ID529  ID646 5.357433
3492653  ID2653  ID699 5.297154
17046659 ID1659 ID3410 5.105343
3323364  ID3364  ID665 4.987266    
...
```

However, because the matrix is large, the first two operations above (`melt`ing the matrix and removing duplicate pairs) take a very long time, often in excess of 5 minutes. I need to apply this operation to several hundred square matrices of variable size (often larger than 5000x5000).

I am sure there must be a faster way to extract this information, because I do not actually need to melt the entire matrix—just the row and column names associated with the top 100,000 values. How can this operation be accomplished more efficiently?

Comment: When you say "top 100,000 unique pairs", do you mean the upper triangle of the matrix `mat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R version using indexing:

```
up <- upper.tri(mat)
inds <- which( up , arr.ind = TRUE )
out <- data.frame( id.A = rownames(mat)[ inds[,1] ] , id.B = rownames(mat)[ inds[,2] ] , value = mat[up] )
#order and select the top ten:
out[order(-out$value),][1:10,]
```

On my machine this is about 3.5x faster than `melt`.

I am assuming that you want the upper triangular part of your matrix.

Note that your `as.character(corDat$id.A) < as.character(corDat$id.B)` statement does NOT select the upper triangular part, because of the way multi-digit string comparisons work (e.g. `"ID10" < "ID7"` evaluates to `TRUE` ).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this point about string comparisons in R, I was not aware of this. Yes, by unique pairs I mean the upper (or lower) triangle of the matrix only—in reality the matrix is symmetric, although I didn't think to make it symmetric in my example.